# group list a join with list b and get the average of items in list b

Tags: linq, list, lambda

I have two lists List A and List B, they can be joined on a common property (Id), what I'm trying to do is group List A on one of its properties (OrgName), joining it with List B. List B contains all answers given to a set of questions. I'd like to get the average score for each question for the organisation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

If it makes it easier List A, is a List of a Submission object. Where submission has members such as Id, firstName, surname, company, email etc and also contains a member answers of type List of an answer object. The answer object has members such as Id, question, answer.

What I'm after is to group the List by company and then get the average score (answer) for each question for that company.

Comment: could you show how your classes look like and give an example input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this two objects to test my answer.

```
public class ObjA
{
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ObjB
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

The following linq expression creates an enumerable that contains an object with a company and a enumerable of all questions and the average scores of all members (Id property of ObjA) that are assigned to that company.

```
var result = listA.Join(listB, a => a.Id, b => b.AId, (a, b) =>
    new
    {
        OrgName = a.OrgName,
        QuestionId = b.QuestionId,
        Score = b.Score
    }).GroupBy(g => g.OrgName).Select(r =>
        new
        {
            OrgName = r.Key,
            AverageByQuestion = r.GroupBy(x => x.QuestionId).Select(y => new { QuestionId = y.Key, Score = y.Average(z => z.Score) })
        });
```